# JOIN of two large tables in two separate SQLite databases seems stuck

Tags: python, sqlite, join, chunks

## Context

I have two tables (`A`, `B`) in two separate SQlite databases (`db1`,`db2`) that I would like to merge (or join, whatever is the correct terminology in database-speak). TABLE `A` has about 150 million records stored in a 161GB database `db1` while TABLE `B` has about 292 million records stored in a 173GB database `db2`. I am trying to merge the two tables by ATTACH-ing `db2` to `db1` and running the canonical JOIN query.

## The problem

The code below has been running for over 4 continuous days without any noticeable changes to db1 database file or its log file. If I run a test query with the `LIMIT 1000` clause, the JOIN works in less than a second. For the full sized tables, the operation seems to run-on forever. I can see that the hard-disk from which the data are being read is in continuous 100% use but it never moves beyond that (so clearly no output to show either).

```
conn =  sqlite3.connect("/".join([data_path, 'db1.db']))
c = conn.cursor()

## attach 2nd db
query = """
ATTACH ".../db2.db" as db2;
"""
c.execute(query)
conn.commit()

## merge query
query = """
CREATE TABLE ABjoined AS
    SELECT  id,col2 FROM A INNER JOIN db2.B
    ON A.id = db2.B.id;
"""

c.execute(query)
c.commit()
```

### Update

I would love to create a minimal reproducible example for but it seems the only trigger is table size. I can only think of generating two 150GB databases to merge but that doesn't seem optimal. I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Have you considered that SQLite may not be the right tool for this job?  (The Lite is there for a reason.)

Comment: @tonypdmtr it's starting to cross mind

Comment: @tonypdmtr on the other hand, SQlite was able to perform a similar-sized JOIN operation but it was all within one database - as opposed to here where there are two. Maybe that's where the devil hides

Comment: According to https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html databases can be up to 140TB. In practice, it may work, but the response times can be 'unacceptable'. I'm not saying SQLite3 cannot handle this much data but possibly a different engine would do it faster. One of the things that are great about SQLite3 is using a single file for holding a complete database. However, this same thing can become its worst enemy as the file size grows too much as the overhead introduced by the FS/OS may slow things down a lot. Just guessing in your specific case if that is a real issue. `INSERT` in transactions helps.

Comment: About having done a similar `JOIN` in a single database within acceptable time, I assume: How about `.dump` the table(s) from the secondary database and load them in the main database, and then do the join?

Comment: Is there a journal file?

Comment: @Shawn yes, there's a journal file but upon glance, it doesn't seem to contain any information beside column names and the data type. Would you suggest to look for something in particular?

Comment: @tonypdmtr indeed, regarding your 2nd point, I dumped the data from the 2nd database into the 1st so that the JOIN command is working with tables in the 1st database. I'll update if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @tonypdmtr Thanks for suggestion! Moving Table `B` into `db1` and then performing the merge all in `db1` worked.

Comment: (Again:) One cannot expect reasonable SQL performance without appropriate indexes. And a SQL [mre] should show them & plans. Before you ask about SQL perfomance read all the manual sections re 'index' & 'optimization'. Including--https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html https://www.sqlite.org https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html/optoverview.html

Answer (score 1):

In seems that merging tables via ATTACH does *not* scale well - at least for my two large tables (ie each at least 150,000,000 by 200) via an attached database in SQLite does **not** quite work. If you encounter a similar problem where the `JOIN` operation gets stuck, I suggest you move TABLE B in db2 into db1 and then perform the JOIN as usual. Namely...

```
conn =  sqlite3.connect("/".join([data_path, 'db1.db']))
c = conn.cursor()

## attach 2nd db
query = """
ATTACH ".../db2.db" as db2;
"""
c.execute(query)

## create an empty table B in db1 and insert from B
query = """CREATE TABLE C(id dtype, col2 dtype);"""
c.execute(query)

## insert table B into table C
query = """INSERT INTO C SELECT id col2 FROM db2.B;"""
c.execute(query)

## detach db2
query = """DETACH db2"""
c.execute(query)

# now merge tables A and C as usual
query = """
CREATE TABLE AC AS
    SELECT  id,col2 FROM A INNER JOIN C
    ON A.id =  C.id;
"""

c.execute(query)
c.commit()
```

The original approach of using attached tables gets stuck whereas inserting TABLE B (300,000,000 by 180) into db1 took about 5 minutes and then TABLE A's merger with TABLE C took less than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

First do this to see how large the resulting table would be:

```
select count(*) 
from A INNER JOIN db2.B
ON A.id = db2.B.id
```

I suspect that your join is multiplying this tables too much.

If the resulting table is too big, let's wonder why.

Once we know how big the table will be, then we can calculate how long it should take.

Finally, I would monitor the Database to see that it's making progress. Is it getting bigger? Are you starting to use the SWAP?